# storing "inputdialog" data in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a Java menu console which asks users to select an option. I have successfully compiled the menu system which takes a users input and directs them to a menu page. The first of these pages asks 2 questions using "InputDialog" boxes.

Here is the code for the "InputDialog", when I run the java console i can access and enter information into these boxes fine.

```
private void enterInfor()
{
    String carInfo;
    int carHours;
    int i = 0;
    double fee = Double.parseDouble("7.50");
    double sum = 0;

    {
        carInfo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the license plate of the car");
        carHours = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of hours the car was parked (1-12):"));

            System.out.printf("\n");
            System.out.printf("Details for car 1 entered:\n");
            System.out.printf("License plate   Hours      Fee:\n");
            System.out.printf(""+carInfo+"           "+carHours+"         $");
                    if (carHours == 1)
                        System.out.printf("%3.2f",fee*(carHours));
                    else if (carHours == 2)
                        System.out.printf("%3.2f",fee+4.50);
                    else if (carHours >= 3)
                        System.out.printf("%3.2f",3+(carHours*4.50));
            System.out.printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

I have the "String" and "int" information to store the information that is input by the user, however I need the program to store at least 20 different inputs which can be accessed later in the console.

I have successfully made a console repeat information and then output the combined answers using a for loop =

```
"for(int Num=1; Num <= 6; Num++)"
```

and this allowed me to repeat a set of questions and then compile the information into statistics afterwards but for this console I need the "InputDialog" to only take in one set of answers at a time and then return the user to the initial console menu.

I'm sorry again if this is all pretty vague of information or formats, just need some kind of help on how/where to put the correct code.

Comment: You are probably correct and I do apologize, this is why I am asking the question as I have only been involved with Java for a short few months and it is a lot to wrap my head around.

Comment: Please understand that Java and JavaScript are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. You'll want to delete that wrong question tag.

Comment: Why you want to store the result in an array? The object orientated way would be to store it as object.

Comment: Would it be more beneficial to store it as an object? As I said previously, I am still trying to get my head around all of this properly. All I require the program to do is store the information from the inputDialog no more than 20 times.